# number of parameters requested in a select statement

Tags: mysql

This is probably a somewhat simple question but I am trying to make sure that a query statement (specifically a select statement) contains a specific number of parameters only:

```
$result = mysql_query("select type,some_other_column from my_table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$number = count($row);
print $number;
```

This returns twice the number I think it should return (4) - as I believe it must also be returning the key and the value as separate parameters.

The select statement above is just an example and it could be any number of statements. They could be a lot more complicated and the tests I have run do not seem to have any problems. I want to make sure that there are only ever two parameters (it can be any two) and they could be from different tables too.

I just want to make sure that it that what I am doing above is both the fastest way to check that the number of parameters is correct and that it won't get upset if there is a much more complicated statement given to it.

I am sure there is a really easy answer to this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Rather curious as to why you're checking the number of columns returned. You should try [mysql_fetch_field](http://us2.php.net/mysql_fetch_field). But also check out MySQL's VIEW's.

Comment: By specific number of "parameters" do you mean specific number of "rows"?

Answer (score 1):

Try [mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) or [mysql_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_row). Both functions available on php.net

[mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) -- Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both. You end up having

```
$row["type"] = "somevalue"; // AND
$row[0] = "somevalue";
```

hence double the number

Comment: thanks.. that is what I thought, I just thought there maybe a cleaner, faster way to get it, and I am sure one of two ways you suggested should do it :)

Comment: If you are working on a project that you want to grow - you may want to use a class wrapper for MySQL. I wrote my own, i'm sure there's a ton out there. Wrappers will help you clean up memory, and have convenient single-function calls to return 1 row, or just first column of the first row. Feel free to message me for details

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you `SELECT` would be in the `$row` variable, so in your code:

```
$result = mysql_query("select type,some_other_column from my_table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
/*
   $row = array(
        'type' => 'type_value',
        '0' => 'type_value',
        'some_other_column' => 'col_value',
        '1' => 'col_value'
   )
*/
$number = count($row); 
print $number; // prints 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understood your question right.

Do you just want to limit your number of returned values to one row?

If this is your point, you can add `LIMIT 1` to your SQL-Query. This would, as it says, limit the number of results to one row.

Comment: He wants to check the number of columns returned, not the number of rows.